# Filter table data using a search box in php

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a Reminder system using PHP.

I'm having a error on my PHP code, hope someone could resolve it for me. Ok first i'll explain the situation. I have data base with two tables, one with the user info and other with the event info.

Event info table details

eventid (int)10 Auto Increment,
email (varchar)40
eventname (varchar)30
descryption (varchar)150
Category (varchar)10
date (date)

After a user logged in he can add events using his email address. Users need to see their events. so i created a php page called "userprofile" when i access the "userprofile" its filters the eventinfo table using email and returns the users events. Now i want to add a filter to filter those data. But when i try to filtered data using the search box it gives an error. (error is : mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string) following is the code

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $email=$_SESSION['user'];


    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("reminder") or die(mysql_error()); 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM eventinfo WHERE email = '{$email}'";

    if(isset($_POST['search'])){

        $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string(['search_box']);

        $sql .= "WHERE eventname = '{$search_term}' ";
        $sql .= "or Category = '{$search_term}'";

    }

    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


?>

<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="userprofile.php">

search: <input type="text" name="search_box" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search">
</form>


<table>
<table width"120%" cellpadding="10" cellspace="10">

    <td><Strong>Event Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Event Date</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Category</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Description</strong></td>



<tr>
</tr>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row ['eventname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row ['date']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row ['Category']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row ['descryption']; ?></td>

</td>
<?php } ?>


</table>
```

---

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string(['search_box'])` you're giving it a list, it expects a string. I think you should give it `$_POST['search_box']` instead. Also this code may be vulnerable to SQL injections if the `$email` isn't properly validated. And `mysql` is deprecated, use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: ^--« This translates to: Change `$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string(['search_box']);` to `$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);` --- Use error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not responding to whatever's been put in the comments box, you might get notification with an actual "answer".

The reason for the error and as  André said, is that you're giving it a list instead of a string, that needs to be processed by a `$_POST` directive.

Change:

```
$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string(['search_box']);
```

to:

```
$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);
```

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.